# Marketing Cloud Reporting by Data Extension as Source

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting

My instance of SFMC does not have Audience Builder configured.

We want to send a single email to 5 segments each with their own data extension.  To do this, we can set up a guided send for the email and select all 5 data extensions and the email goes out to all 5.

Now, we want to report on performance of this email by data extension.
Ex: DE1 had open rate of 40%, DE2 open rate 30%, DE3 open rate 35% and so on.

Is there a way to do this with SFMC reporting tools without needing to write a query?

Comment: I believe you may be able to create something via the Blank template in Discover reporting - using the 'Source Name' field. If you just need a quick look at it, you can get the info via the Tracking overview. There is a 'select recipient' button on top left that lets you select the data sources you want to track for current view.

Comment: How about setting up 5 different guided sends / user-initiated sends for 5 different DEs? In this way you can track the email send differently in tracking without any hassle.

Comment: thanks @Gortonington.  That is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: moved it to an answer for easier reference if someone else has this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to create something via the Blank template in [Discover reporting](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/discover/discover_reports/) - using the 'Source Name' field to identify each of your Data Extensions.

If you just need a quick look at the information and not anything formal, you can get the info quickly via the Tracking overview page for each send. There is a 'select recipient' button on top left that lets you select the data sources you want to track for current view and will refresh the numbers for you depending on the sources selected.